# How to insert an iframe in a slack integration?

Tags: iframe, slack-api, slack

The youtube slack integration inserts an image and when that image is clicked a youtube.com iframe gets inserted.

[image: youtube iframe slack integration]

How can my custom slack integration also insert an iframe? For example say I'd like to insert a codepen iframe?

Answer (score 4):

This is not something Slack allows third-party integrations to do. (Slack itself "unfurls" certain media links, like YouTube videos.)